# How use context from constructor?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-context, behavior

Right now i have class which implement `Behavior` and i use context with next code, can i simplify it?

```
class FabBehavior: CoordinatorLayout.Behavior<FloatingActionButton> {

    private var myContext: Context? = null
    private val fabDefaultBottomMargin = myContext?.resources?.getDimension(R.dimen.dp_16)?.toInt() ?: 0

    constructor() : super()
    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : super(context, attrs) {
        myContext = context
    }
```

**UPDATE**:

Also i tried smth like this:

```
class FabBehavior(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?): CoordinatorLayout.Behavior<FloatingActionButton>(context, attrs) {

    private val fabDefaultBottomMargin = context.resources?.getDimension(R.dimen.dp_16)?.toInt() ?: 0

    constructor(context: Context) : this(context, null)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is this:

```
  class FabBehavior(private val context: Context?, attrs: AttributeSet?) : CoordinatorLayout.Behavior<FloatingActionButton>(context, attrs) {

      fun doSomething() {
       context.invokeMethodOnContext()
    }
}
```